# Exibir 1, 2, 3 se recebe números ímpares

Tags: java, android

Preciso que no *textview* exiba na ordem 1, 2, 3, 4 etc. Porém o valor que ele recebe de `dados.getdia()` é sempre 3, 5, 7, 9, 11 etc. Já tentei várias coisas.

Neste código abaixo ele funciona até quando recebe 5, depois quando recebe 7, ele exibe 5 em vez de 4, que seria o correto. Como posso fazer isso?

```
int dia = dados.getDia();
if(dia == 3){
    Log.d(TAG,"entrou Dia ==3");
    int dia2 = dia-1 ;
    txv_dia.setText(String.valueOf(dia2));
}else if(dia >3){
    Log.d(TAG,"entrou Dia >3");
    int dia2 = dia-3 ;
    txv_dia.setText(String.valueOf(dia2));
}
```

Comment: Parece fácil resolver seu problema, mas eu mal entendi o que você tentou explicar. Teria como detalhar mais um pouco? Você quer mostrar somente dias impares? ou somente pares?

Comment: Quero exibir 1,2,3 porem recebo impares, mas parece que consegui resolver aqui, fiz um contador e faço a  subtração do dia - contado, to fazendo os testes aqui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como acredito eu que você queira imprimir a posição dos números primos, não pode ter o == 3, >3 e -3, pois a diferença entre os números sempre aumentam.

Terá que tratá-los considerando essa diferença entre eles para achar a posição.